# Crystal Report : how to mark a value in stacked bar chart

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image: stacked bar chart with highlights]

I need to display values in the stacked bar chart as shown in the figure. The stacked bar chart is created with standard score. And, the score obtained by a person is marked as highlights.I need help to show the values(17.6,29.4...)

Answer (score 1):

One of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs (User Function Libraries) listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) allows you to achieve similar output using Bullet Charts. Here is a sample output:
[image: Bullet Charts in a Crystal Report using a UFL]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The vended application that the reports run do not allow any third party tools. Is there an option within crystal reports that can at least highlight the value.